# How to hide an input based on dropdown

Tags: javascript, forms, input, dropdown

I have a login form where users can choose their country from a drop-down, and I would like to show the 'If other specify' option only when the user selects 'other' from the dropdown.

I have found many other answers to this question, but they are using jQuery, and I would like to use pure JavaScript.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<form>
    Username/Name:<br><input type="text"><br>
    Country:<br>
    <select id="country" name="country">
        <option value="us">United States   </option>
        <option value="uk">United Kingdom  </option>
        <option value="ca">Canada  </option>
        <option value="othr">Other  </option>
    </select><br>
    If other specify:<br><input type="text"><br>
    Password:<br><input type="text"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In">
</form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the typo of othr to other.

Wrap the stuff you want to show/hide in an element with ID of "other-container", then

```
function handleCountryChange(event) {
     var display = event.target.value == 'other' ? 'inline' : 'none';
     otherContainer.style.display = display;
}

var otherContainer = document.getElementById('other-container');
var countrySelect = document.getElementById('country');

countrySelect.addEventListener('change', handleCountryChange)
```